# how to make ajax call to parse xml schema

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

I need to parse (xml schema) with ajax call from client side. The following is the function. Let me know what I'm doing wrong. thanks.

```
$.ajax({
        url: webServiceURL, 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml", 
        data: soapMessage, 
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        complete: OnSuccess            
    });

function OnSuccess(xmlHttpRequest, status)
{
    $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML)
    .find('Result')
    .each(function()
    {
        return $(this).find('xsd\\:schema').text();
    });
}
```

Here's my SOAP reponse’s schema/definition

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Response xmlns="Auto Services">
      <Result>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</Result>
    </Response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: So what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Paul: I don't get any output

Comment: You're not writing output anywhere.  `OnSuccess` (which is badly named since it is for the `complete` event, which executes if the op is successful or not) just returns the first instance it finds.  You shouldn't even be returning anything here since there is nothing that will receive the returned value.

Comment: @Paul: well I am trying to load the schema first, then parse the xml it generates.

Comment: Again, what exactly isn't working?  Is the webServiceURL being called?  Is OnSuccess being called?  Is the `status` "success" or something else?  What is the raw value of `xmlHttpRequest.responseXML`?  Saying you're getting no output when there is no code producing output is not telling me where the problem is.